# MySQL: ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails - but only for 1 sql file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to import data from sql files into local MySQL database. I'm using WampServer2.5, MySQL 5.6.17. I'm importing them using MySQL console as PHPMyAdmin interface was causing some problems.

First two files seem to be uploaded correctly. However, they were much smaller than the third one. The steps are always the same:

```
1. create database xyz;
2. use database xyz;
3. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
4. source path/to/the/xyz.sql
```

When uploading the third file at some point I get this errors (a couple in a row, then it keeps uploading):

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:  [some number]
Current database: xyz
```

Then a get a few of those, which is strange as I set that in the beginning (maybe there is some reset of this setting when connection is lost?):

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

The result is I have all the tables uploaded, but some of them have no data - mostly because they are referencing user table from that third database, which has no records.

Ideas / questions:

1. I tried to edit php.ini file to increase memory limit, max file upload size but there is no effect on PHPMyAdmin interface
2. Can I find only one table in sql file and upload the records to the table in my MYSQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table was updated after I opened the full sql file i Notepad++, found only lines with inserted values into that particular table, saved it as a new sql file and used 'source' command then.